# How to use generated textures (eg. wave) as normal map?

Tags: texturing

I would like to use the generated wave texture as a normal map.
It is a mesh with different materials assigned.

I try to plug in the wave texture directly into the normal map node but it doesn't work like that. Can I convert somehow the output of the wave texture ?
I'm quite confuse how to proceed and how to do it.

[image: screenshot of material setup]

Answer (score 4):

Normal maps expect RGB chanels to represent the XYZ axis of the surface.

A monochrome texture like wave only has one component and can't effectively be used as a Normal Map directly.

What you need is to convert it into a bump map which represents height values from a single component instead, that can be used to influence normals.

Use a *Vector > Bump* node instead

[image]